# sample .apk file fore testing the Directory traversal vulnerability

Tags: ruby

I am looking to get a .apk file for testing the Directory traversal vulnerability.

https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/315

We have upgraded the rubyzip gem to address this issue. And I want find sample .apk file for testing the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the book, Hacking Android, covers the [Adobe Reader 10.3.1 APK](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222213312/http://blog.seguesec.com/2012/09/path-traversal-vulnerability-on-adobe-reader-android-application/) (Adobe_Reader_10.3.1.apk) using the free open-source attack tool, MWR Labs Drozer. The book section title is Path traversal in content providers, part of Chapter 8 on Client-Side Attacks - Dynamic Analysis Techniques.

> dz> run scanner.provider.traversal -a com.adobe.reader
>
> Scanning com.adobe.reader...
> Vulnerable Providers:
>
> content://com.adobe.reader.fileprovider

MWR Labs Drozer includes a purposely-vulnerable APK called Sieve. If you want to write code to exploit Sieve, check out the -- https://github.com/tanprathan/sievePWN -- project, which includes source code to build your own APK2APK attacks, including the targeting of Directory (aka Path) Traversal. If you search for "apk path-traversal" you are bound to find dozens, if not hundreds, more.